# Error al mostrar imagen en Android

Tags: android, bitmap

**Android** me esta marcando este error, pero la verdad no tengo ni la menor idea de porqué ya que esta realizando mi proceso correctamente y me muestra la imagen:

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/www.paisajesbonitos.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/paisajes-de-chile-patagonia-chile-paisajes-bonitos-hermosos-2.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://www.paisajesbonitos.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/paisajes-de-chile-patagonia-chile-paisajes-bonitos-hermosos-2.jpg
>
> IndexActivity.java

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (checkIn.getImages().size() > 0) {//valido de que existan imagenes
        for (ImageData object: checkIn.getImages()) {
            strings.add(object.getPath());//al ArrayList le agrego los Bitmaps
        }//for
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, strings));//seteo las imagenes al gridView
    }//./if
```

> InameAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> imagesList;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imagesList){
    super(context, R.layout.activity_index, imagesList);//recibe como parametros el Contexto y un ArrayList de Bitmaps
    this.mContext = context;//se asgina valores
    this.imagesList = imagesList;//se asgina valores
}//./constructor

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));

    for (int i = 0; i < imagesList.size(); i++) {
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(imagesList.get(i));

        if (imagesList.size() > 0) {
            imageView.setImageURI(myUri);
        }
    }

    Glide.with(mContext).load(imagesList.get(position)).into(imageView);

    return imageView;
}
```

}//./clase

Comment: puedes agregar el codigo que estas usando para setear esa imagen?

Comment: Hola sioesi, claro que si

Comment: listo, pero no se porque lo marca si el proceso lo realiza bien y las imagenes se ven

Comment: esta en el getView en el if, ahi es donde paso la URL de la imagen y la setteo al ImageView

Comment: no porque la conexion es estable aparte tengo una validacion donde si no esta conectado a una red wifino se abra la aplicacion y lo que pasa es que sis se abre pero cuando ingreso un codipo para ver el item se cierra la aplicacion

Comment: @Javierfr no es necesario el for que comento en mi respuesta, únicamente la carga de la imagen en el ImageView mediante Glide.

Answer (score 2):

El error es **FileNotFoundException** :

> Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http:/www.paisajesbonitos.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/paisajes-de-chile-patagonia-chile-paisajes-bonitos-hermosos-2.jpg

tal vez si cargas el archivo en un browser el archivo existe pero pueden ser 2 cosas, tu aplicación al momento de cargar la url esta offline, o el servidor no esta respondiendo correctamente al tratar de entregar la imagen, en pocas palabras el recurso no se encuentra.

Pero ademas tienes este error:

> resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:

Este error pudiera estar provocando el anterior, lo que noto es que estas cargando en el mismo `ImageView` todas las imagenes! que contiene el ArrayList mdiante `setImageURI()`, en este punto solo debes cargar una definida por `position`:

```
  imageView.setImageURI(myUri);
```

Pero después de cargar la imagen, también lo realizas nuevamente con `Glide`:

```
 Glide.with(mContext).load(imagesList.get(position)).into(imageView);
```

El `for` que tienes para cargar la imagen no es necesario ya que la imagen requerida se obtiene mediante `position` dentro del `ArrayList` que contiene las imágenes y esta la estas cargando con `Glide` dentro del `ImageView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));

   /* for (int i = 0; i < imagesList.size(); i++) {
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(imagesList.get(i));

        if (imagesList.size() > 0) {
            imageView.setImageURI(myUri);
        }
    }*/

    Glide.with(mContext).load(imagesList.get(position)).into(imageView);

    return imageView;
}
```

---

Si no deseas usar Glide esta sería la forma de cargar la(s) imagen:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));

    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(imagesList.get(position));
    imageView.setImageURI(myUri);

   /* for (int i = 0; i < imagesList.size(); i++) {
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(imagesList.get(i));

        if (imagesList.size() > 0) {
            imageView.setImageURI(myUri);
        }
    }    
    Glide.with(mContext).load(imagesList.get(position)).into(imageView);
    */

    return imageView;
}
```

> Yo lo realize asi

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));

    if (imagesList.size() > 0) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imagesList.get(position));
    }
    return imageView;
}
```

}//./clase

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50701/discussion-on-answer-by-elenasys-error-al-mostrar-imagen-en-android).